# When you don’t have to move (bonus card), do you pick up your separated assistant or do you have to separate another one?

Tags: istanbul

My question is about this bonus card:

[image: Istanbul: bonus card which allows your merchant to stay on a field]

When playing it at the beginning of your turn, you don’t have to move your merchant (and you may use the field’s action).

The rules say that you "again" have to use one of your assistants for this, but I’m not sure if this *always* applies (i.e., not following the normal movement rules), or if it only applies if you would have to use an assistant as if you had moved normally.

1. Situation after the first turn:

   - Situation A: Your merchant is on top of all his assistants (from that field), because you have picked the assistant up that was left there.
   - Situation B: No assistant was on the field, so you had to separate one assistant. Now your merchant is on top of 1+ assistants, and next to them is one assistant.
2. Second turn begins and you play the bonus card, so you stay on this field:

   - In situation A: You have to separate one of your assistants and he will be left there when you move on in your third turn.
   - In situation B: Do you have to **separate another assistant** (so leaving two assistants when moving on in the next turn), or do you **pick up your previously separated assistant** (leaving no-one when moving on in the next turn)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Act as if you would have moved your Merchant.

So if you play this card while an Assistant is separated (from your previous turn), you **pick this assistant up** and play the Place’s action.

The [rules](http://www.pegasus.de/fileadmin/_downloads/regeln/englisch/Istanbul_-_Anleitung_gb.pdf) say "Your Merchant stays at his current Place but you have to use an Assistant again", however, "use an Assistant" does not necessarily mean to separate one. You also *use* an Assistant if you visit a previously visited Place and pick this Assistant up.

#### References

This question gets discussed in these threads on BoardGameGeek:

- [Some questions about rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1122376/some-questions-about-rules)

  - André Bronswijk [confirms](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/14872147#14872147) it
  - Grzegorz Kobiela [confirms](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/15831032#15831032) and [explains](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/15831395#15831395) it
- [Bonus Card, which lets you stay where you are](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1176879/bonus-card-which-lets-you-stay-where-you-are)
- [Need clarification about the "Do not move your Merchant" Bonus Card](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1198220/need-clarification-about-do-not-move-your-merchant)

  - Ralph Bruhn [confirms and explains](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/16233121#16233121) it
- [No movement card](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1270534/no-movement-card)

  - Ralph Bruhn [confirms](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/17617415#17617415) it indirectly